# Please identify LEGO sets based on these parts

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

Any ideas what set they belong?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have the fuselage of [4618 Twin Rotor Cargo](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4618-1):

[image]

The red windshield is from one of these sets (the yellow sticker does not belong):

- [70706: Crater Creeper](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70706-1)
- [4621: Jack Stone Red Flash Station](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4621-1)
- [4796: Ogel Mutant Squid](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4796-1)
- [9320: Voyage into Space (Journey Into Space Set)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=9320-1)

And the 2x3 slope is from one of [these sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3298p10).